# Is there a way to access QMainWindowPrivate or QMainWindowLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm using Qt5 and I am trying to do this:

```
setCentralWidget(wid);
...
setCentralWidget(nullptr); // i don't want it to do deleteLater() for my wid variable
...
setCentralWidget(wid);
```

The problem is that, when I call `setCentralWidget(nullptr)`, it does `deleteLater()` for my `wid` variable.

So, I found a way to use `setCentralWidget()` without deleting the `wid` variable:

```
Q_D(QMainWindow);
d->layout->setCentralWidget(nullptr);
```

But the question is: How to use private headers or widgets or whatever? I mean, I don't have access to `QMainWindowPrivate` or `QMainWindowLayout`, because they are private. So is there a way to access them?

Comment: This sounds like an xy-problem. Why do you want to replace the central widget? Why not simply change the widget hierarchy parented by the central widget instead?

Comment: i got errors on other widgets for that reason. and i want to replace it because i want to make my QDockWidget fullscreen

Comment: Instead of `setCentralWidget(nullptr);`, you could use [takeCentralWidget();](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#takeCentralWidget). This "plugs out" `wid` releasing the ownership which `QMainWindow` has before. Some of the Qt classes provide such `take` functions for this purpose. Otherwise, I used successful a different trick: resetting the parent of the resp. child widget to "plug out": `wid->setParent(nullptr);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's issue is caused by using `setCentralWidget(nullptr);`.

[QMainWindow::setCentralWiget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget):

> Sets the given widget to be the main window's central widget.
>
> **Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Hence, for

```
setCentralWidget(wid);
...
setCentralWidget(nullptr);
```

it has to be expected that the `QMainWindow` will delete the `wid`. Otherwise, the `wid` instance could become orphaned i.e. a memory leak.

However, OPs issue can be solved without adventurous accesses to internals of `QMainWindow` (which is neither intended nor necessary).

In fact, there is an alternative to remove the central widget and take over the ownership again – [QMainWindow::takeCentralWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#takeCentralWidget):

> Removes the central widget from this main window.
>
> **The ownership of the removed widget is passed to the caller.**

(Emphasis mine, again.)

An MCVE to demonstrate this:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("QMainWindow::takeCentralWidget");
  QLabel *pQLbl = new QLabel("The\ncentral\nwidget");
  pQLbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
  qWinMain.setCentralWidget(pQLbl);
  qWinMain.show();
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(1000);
  uint n = 10;
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      --n;
      if (!n) {
        qWinMain.setCentralWidget(nullptr);
        app.quit();
      } else if (n & 1) qWinMain.setCentralWidget(pQLbl);
      else qWinMain.takeCentralWidget();
    });
  // runtime loop
  qTimer.start();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:
[image: Snapshot of testQMainWindow-takeCentralWidget]